# Как сохранить dialogFragment при повороте телефона

Tags: android, dialogfragment, dialog

Доброго времени суток товарищи. Есть диалог фрагмент (отдельный класс) который создается через интерфейс по клику по пункту в listView (клик обрабатывается в адаптере и вызывает интерфейс в активити).
В этот диалог передаются данные (для редактирования и сохранения в БД).
Как мне при повороте телефона сохранить состояние диалога? Точнее состояние самого диалога я сохраняю вот так:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (builder != null) {
            savedInstanceState.putBoolean("showDialog", true);
            savedInstanceState.putString("id", String.valueOf(id));
            savedInstanceState.putString("key", key);
            if (!String.valueOf(posTextView.getText()).equals("")) {
                savedInstanceState.putDouble("posTextView", Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(posTextView.getText())));
            } else {
                savedInstanceState.putDouble("posTextView", 0);
            }
            if (!String.valueOf(priceTextView.getText()).equals("")) {
                savedInstanceState.putDouble("priceTextView", Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(priceTextView.getText())));
            } else {
                savedInstanceState.putDouble("priceTextView", 0);
            }
            savedInstanceState.putLong("dateLong", resultDate);
        } else {
            savedInstanceState.putBoolean("showDialog", false);
        }
    }
```

И восстанавливаю

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("showDialog")) {
        this.id= savedInstanceState.getInt("id");
        this.key= savedInstanceState.getString("key");
        this.quantity = savedInstanceState.getDouble("posTextView");
        this.price = savedInstanceState.getDouble("priceTextView");
        this.dateLong = savedInstanceState.getLong("dateLong");
    }
```

Как мне в активити после поворота вызвать диалог с этими данными? Не создавая новый если старый не был закрыт.
Конструктор диалога (даже после восстановления данных будет требовать контекст иначе нуллПоинтерЕксепшен)

```
 public EditPortfolioDialogFragment newInstance(Integer id, String key, double quantity, double price, long dateLong,
                                                   boolean buy, Context context, PortfolioItemSaveListener portfolioItemSaveListener) {
        EditPortfolioDialogFragment dialogFragment = new EditPortfolioDialogFragment();

        this.coinId = id;
        if (key != null) {
            this.key = key;
            this.oldKey = key;
        } else {
            this.key = "abc";
        }
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.dateLong = dateLong;

        this.context = context;
        this.portfolioItemSaveListener = portfolioItemSaveListener;
        return dialogFragment;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

По идее в методе `onCreate` добавив это, проблема должна быть решена.

Comment: В onCreate активити? В диалог просто добавлял, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: да, в диалоге. Ну тогда не знаю